# Button command won't bind to UserControll class

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, command

Here's my user control code:

```
<UserControl .... x:Name="UserControl" />
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" DataContext="{Binding ElementName=UserControl, Mode=OneWay}" >
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Websites}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellEditEnding="DataGrid_CellEditEnding" BeginningEdit="DataGrid_BeginningEdit">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            ...
            <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Button .... CommandParameter="{Binding}" >
                            <Button.Content>
                                <Image Source="./../Images/close.png" Width="15"></Image>
                            </Button.Content>
                            <Button.Command>                                                            
                                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource TriggerConverter}">
                                    <Binding ElementName="UserControl" Path="DataContext.DeleteCommand" >
                                        </Binding>
                                    <Binding />
                                </MultiBinding> 
                            </Button.Command>                               
                        </Button>
                    </DataTemplate>                                             
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>                                          
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>         
    </DataGrid>     
</Grid>

    CDeleteCommand dc = null;

    public ICommand DeleteCommand
    {
        get 
        {
            if (dc!=null)
            {
                return dc;
            }
            return dc = new CDeleteCommand() { Pannel = this };
        }
    }
```

I've got a breakpoint at the DeleteCommand.get, and it never gets triggered.

Here's the binding error that I'm getting:

```
Cannot find source for binding with reference 'ElementName=UserControl'. 
BindingExpression:Path=DataContext.DeleteCommand; DataItem=null; target element is
 'Button' (Name=''); target property is 'Command' (type 'ICommand')
```

Why not and how do I fix it?

Comment: Know how to [debug data bindings](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpfsldesigner/archive/2010/06/30/debugging-data-bindings-in-a-wpf-or-silverlight-application.aspx)?

Comment: It tells me that it can't find an element with name 'UserControl': Cannot find source for binding with reference 'ElementName=UserControl. I've got the UserControl named, and the name  matches exactly

Comment: That's at least a starting point, but i for one have no time to deal with this. (Could try a `RelativeSource` binding instead and see if that throws an error, if it does look for that error and questions related to data binding in DataGrids, they can be tricky)

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here?  Typically, a `Command` is static and you'd assign it directly - what is it that your `TriggerConverter` does, and why is your `DeleteCommand` not static?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UserControl` is not accessible from `DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate`.

You can try `RelativeSource`

```
"{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}},
                                Path=DataContext.DeleteCommand}"
```

or add your ViewModel to resources and get it via `StaticResource`

```
"{Binding DeleteCommand, Source={StaticResource ViewModel}}"
```

Here's what it should look like for MultiBinding:

```
<MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource TriggerConverter}">
    <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}" 
        Path="DataContext.DeleteCommand" />
    <Binding />
</MultiBinding>
```